# Как получить ссылки на профили в других социальных сетях из Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

На сколько мне известно, Facebook позволяет в информации о профиле указывать ссылки на сторонние сервисы (ВК, Twitter, Instagram). Можно ли эти данные получить с помощью Graph API? Сам долго искал, но найти не получилось.

Comment: Имеется ввиду ссылки на профили пользователя в других социальных сетях